# Como adicionar e remover classes com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Quero saber como adicionar e remover uma classe em elementos do HTML com JavaScript.

```html
<div>
 <ul>
  <li class="Active">1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe a API [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), que é basicamente um [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) que contém todas as classes de um determinado elemento.

A propriedade `classList` pode ser acessada em objetos que implementam [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

Primeiro você obtém o elemento:

```
const element = document.querySelector('#my-element');
```

E depois pode...

1. Adicionar uma nova classe à lista:

   ```
   element.classList.add('new-class');
   ```
2. Remover uma classe da lista:

   ```
   element.classList.remove('new-class');
   ```
3. Trocar uma classe por outra:

   ```
   element.classList.replace('old-class', 'new-class');
   ```
4. Fazer o *toggle* de uma classe. Isto é, adicionar a classe se não existir e, caso contrário, remover:

   ```
   element.classList.toggle('is-active');
   ```

Como a propriedade `classList` nada mais é que um `DOMTokenList`, existem [diversos outros métodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList#methods) que podem ajudar em outras situações.

---

A vantagem da API `classList` é que você não precisa modificar *toda* a string de classes diretamente (o que é necessário com a API `className`). Ela também possui vários métodos que tornam o trabalho mais simples. Alguns deles foram demonstrados acima.

Sobre o suporte dessa API, consulte a [tabela](https://caniuse.com/classlist). Embora é mais recente que a API `className`, o suporte para navegadores modernos já é relativamente bom.

Answer (score 2):

Para remover a classe, defina a classe do elemento para vazio:

```
// Pega o primeiro li e remove a classe
document.getElementsByName("li")[0].className = "";
```

Se quiser manter alguma classe, resete a classe:

```
document.getElementsByName("li")[0].className = "";
document.getElementsByName("li")[0].className = "classe_que_fica";
```

Answer (score 0):

Com JavaScript puro, pensei em algo como:

```
// Selecionando elemento no DOM
elemento = document.getElementsByName('li')[0];

// Limpando o atributo class
elemento.className = '';

// Se você quisesse remover uma classe específica, digamos que houvesse
// mais de uma classe no seu elemento (class="Active estilo1"):
element.className = element.className.replace('estilo1','');

// a linha de comando anterior, resultaria em class="Active ", o que 
// significa que você retirou o texto correspondente da classe "estilo1".
// Para remover o espaço extra, pode utilizar .trim() :
element.className = element.className.trim();
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça detalhes adicionais em sua resposta. Como está escrita atualmente, é difícil entender sua solução.

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.